# How do I make my counter work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that adds div when I press a button.
I have a counter re-setting logic written in the removal which should re-count all my names.

my problem is that when I add say 3 items, and remove the 2nd Item, my 3rd item does not rename itself.

what am I doing wrong with this?

```
 $(function () {
     var rowItem = $(".row", $(".formitems")); //select all rows from class formitems
     $(".formitems").on("click", ".addRow", function () {
         var newItem = rowItem.clone(),
             rowIndex = $(".row", $(".formitems")).length;
         $(":input", newItem).each(function (c, obj) {
             $(obj).attr("name", $(obj).attr("crap") + rowIndex);
         });
         $(".formitems").append(newItem); // adds At the end of the container
     }).on("click", ".removeRow", function () {
         if ($(".row", $(".formitems")).length > 1) {
             var target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent(".row");
             target.slideUp(function () {
                 target.remove();
             });
         }
         for (i = 0; i < $(".row", $(".formitems")).length; i++) //select our div called //formitems and then count rows in it
         {
             rowobj = $(".row", $(".formitems"))[i];
             $(":input", rowobj).each(function (c, obj) {
                 $(obj).attr("name", $(obj).attr("crap") + i);
             })
         }
     });
 });
```

EDIT : Ok, So  I put up alerts just before and after using remove(). Does jquery takes time to re-calulate all the properties? If yes, are they cached? If yes, can I force refresh them.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand, you want to update the 'name's after the removal. But the code does the remove() asynchronously when slideUp() completed, while the renaming is invoked immediately after invoking the slideUp(), *before* remove() is called.

You can solve this by placing the renaming code after the call to remove(), inside the slideUp() handler:

```
 }).on("click", ".removeRow", function () {
     if ($(".row", $(".formitems")).length > 1) {
         var target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent(".row");
         target.slideUp(function () {
             target.remove();

             // rename now!
             for (i = 0; i < $(".row", $(".formitems")).length; i++) {
               rowobj = $(".row", $(".formitems"))[i];
               $(":input", rowobj).each(function (c, obj) {
                $(obj).attr("name", $(obj).attr("crap") + i);
               })
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Can you please tell me some reference where I can know what is synchronous and what is not?

I just did an experiment, I used the debugger to observe this, and truly this is what happened, and now it is working.!

Comment: Well, the libraries reference should tell.. However, here it is obvious, because the sliding up is performed before the complete callback is invoked - as the slideUp should really not be blocking the JS-queue, the callback needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: Which is why my function worked sometimes and sometimes not. I guess i need to read the internals a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simplifying your life.

```
<input type="text" name="blah[]" />
```

You can have as many of these elements as you want. The server will receive an array of values, meaning you don't have to manually count them.

Comment: Assuming the server runs PHP. If not, then `name="blah"` would be more appropriate (or maybe other server side languages also treat `[]` in a special way, I don't know).

Comment: @niet -  NO, I cannot use this because the server side stuff cannot be changed by me. The requirement is to have names like a1,a2 ... an.

Comment: Well that's silly... poor backend design there, unfortunately, leaving you with the hard work.